# failed to list w3wp.exe process

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.net. Actually I want to debug the .net application. I am using
Windows 7, Visual studio 2003(restricted to this version for some project),and IIS.

But when I click on debug->processes(show all processes) it is listing w3wp.exe of type WIN32 not .net. I want .net type of w3wp.exe process. Please help me with this.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach to **`aspnet_wp.exe`** process

try follwoing

```
1) From the Debug menu, select Processes. (You can also use Debug Processes from the Tools menu.)
2) Select Show system processes , find aspnet_wp.exe in the Process column and click it.
        The aspnet_wp.exe process is the process that loads your code and displays it in Internet Explorer
```